# How do i wait until a String returns a value?

Tags: c#, asynchronous

I have a program that uses the `KeyPress` event to add a new character to a new `Label`, sort of like a Console Application.
I need to add an `Input` method into my program so when I press enter instead of executing a function, it returns a string. I have tried making the `KeyPress` event return a string but it doesn't work for obvious reasons, how do I make this work?

Note: By "return a string" I mean;

If i where to ask the `Console` to wait for an input I would still be using the `KeyPress` event but it would return a string/input from the user.

I hope you understand the code i have already written, note that it extends into other

My KeyPress event handler:

```
private void Form1_KeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.KeyChar == '\b') // Backspace
        {
            if (ll.Text != "_" && ActualText != "") // Are there any characters to remove?
            {
                ActualText = ll.Text.Substring(0, ActualText.Length - 1);
                ll.Text = ActualText + "_";
            }

        }
        else
            if (e.KeyChar == (char)13)
            {
                if (!inputmode)
                {
                    foreach (KeyValuePair<string, Action> cm in Base.Command())
                    {

                        if (ActualText == cm.Key)
                        {
                            print(ActualText);
                            cm.Value();

                        }
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    inputmode = false;
                    lastInput = ActualText;
                    print("Input >> "+lastInput); 
                }
                ActualText = "";
                ll.Text = ActualText + "_";
            }
            else
            if (!Char.IsControl(e.KeyChar)) // Ignore control chars such as Enter.
            {
                ActualText = ActualText + e.KeyChar.ToString();
                ll.Text = ActualText + "_";
            }
    }
```

Comment: How about you post your code?

Comment: What kind of program, is it a Console Application / WPF / Winforms?

Comment: It is a Windows Forms application.

Comment: @DanielJones is my code helped you?

Comment: No, but i have posted my code that I am working with at the moment. i also explained a bit more above the code. thanks.

Answer (score 2):

your question is a bit unclear, but if i got it right, then the solution is instead of return a string, which you obviously can't in `KeyPress` event, raise your own event, like so

```
public delegate void EnterPressedHndlr(string myString);

public partial class Form1 : Form
{
  public event EnterPressedHndlr EnterPressed;

  void Form1_KeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
  {
     //your calculation
     if (EnterPressed != null)
     {
        EnterPressed("your data");
     }
  }
}
```